# PHP While Loop Not Liking Two Variables

Tags: php

I have the follow while loop in my code. I can't understand why it causes a loading error but when I remove the = from the statement, it suddenly works? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code (Yes, I do have a form opening and closing tags!):

```
 echo "<select name='cquantity'>";
 $x = 0;
 $limit = 1;
 while ($x <= $limit) {
    echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";    
 }
 echo "</select>";
```

Comment: forgot to increase `$x`?

Comment: `<option value='0'>0</option><option value='0'>0</option><option value='0'>0</option><option value='0'>0</option>`....................

Comment: You're not incrementing `$x` and have an infinite while loop.

Comment: Ahh my bad! Forgot about increasing!

Answer (score 4):

You need to increment your x otherwise it's stuck in the loop forever.

```
while($x <= $limit){
    echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
    $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At no time are you incrementing your `$x` variable.

```
 echo "<select name='cquantity'>";
 $x = 0;
 $limit = 1;
 while ($x <= $limit) {
    echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";  
    $x++;  
 }
 echo "</select>";
```

The same could be achieved with a for/loop (made especially for this case)

```
 echo "<select name='cquantity'>";

 for ( $x=0; $x <= 1; $x++ ){
    echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";    
 }
 echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `while` loop you should increment the variable to `$x` otherwise theres infinite loop.

```
while ($x <= $limit) {
    echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";    
     $x++;
 }
```